# XMLHttpRequest: The object's state must be OPENED and GET returns 0

Tags: javascript, json

So I created a button that fetches JSON data from: https://learnwebcode.github.io/json-example/animals-1.json

I created the HTML:

```
 <div class="card-body">
       Show animals &nbsp;
       <button type="button" id="prikaziZiv" class="btn btn-primary">Prikaži</button>

       <div id="zivotinje"></div>
  </div>
```

And the following JSON request:

```
/*Ajax*/
var nasZahtev = new XMLHttpRequest();

nasZahtev.open('GET', 'https://learnwebcode.github.io/json-example/animals-1.json', true);

var zivotinjeContainer = document.getElementById("zivotinje");
var dugme = document.getElementById("prikaziZiv");

dugme.addEventListener("click", function(){

    nasZahtev.onload = function(){

        var nasiPodaci = JSON.parse(nasZahtev.responseText);

        dodajHTML(nasiPodaci);
    };
    nasZahtev.send();
});

function dodajHTML(data){
    var htmlString = "";

    for (i=0; i < data.length; i++){
        htmlString += "<p>" + data[i].name + " je " + data[i].species + ".</p>";
    };

    zivotinjeContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', htmlString);
};
```

The problem is I get two errors:
GET https://learnwebcode.github.io/json-example/animals-1.json 0 ()
(anonymous) @ action.js:44

and

Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': The object's state must be OPENED.
    at HTMLButtonElement. (http://localhost/praksaportal/js/action.js:44:15)

[image]

What am I missing here ?